# javascript to check if property has setter

Tags: javascript

I have an object with properties defined like this:

```
Object.defineProperty(this, 'Prop', {
    get: function () {
        return _Prop;
    },
    set: function (val) {
        _Prop = val;
    },
    enumerable: true
});
```

but some properties are get-only like this:

```
Object.defineProperty(this, 'Prop2', {
    get: function () {
        return _Prop2;
    }
    enumerable: true
});
```

is there a way to check to see if a particular property is get-only? I'm thinking usage like this:

```
if(myObject.hasOwnProperty(myProp) && hasSetter(myObject[myProp])){
    //set myProp
}
```

On compatibility, I only need to support IE11 and newer.

Comment: You can get the property descriptor with `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor` and then inspect it.

Comment: check out Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, prop)

Comment: `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(myObject, 'myProp').set`